# PHP textbox loop

Tags: php, loops, input, textarea

Say I am taking the following information from a `textarea`:

> Coding is cool
>
> Programming is coding
>
> Green screens

I can print it out with bl2br, however what I want it to look like when it's printed out is this:

```
<div class="coding">Coding is cool</div><div class="green"><?php //php query doing the same, but for another textbox ?></div><div class="one-more-class"></div>
<div class="coding">Programming is coding</div><?php //php query doing the same, but for another textbox ?></div><div class="one-more-class"></div>
<div class="coding">Green screens</div><?php //php query doing the same, but for another textbox ?></div><div class="one-more-class"></div>
```

The input has to be from textarea, not from separate textboxes. I'm not going into even more complex jQuery implementation. And speaking of which, no Javascript for this one - I believe it can be done with PHP.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "doing the same?"

Comment: Doing what I've described - getting and sorting data in the same way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get the array of entries:

```
$ar = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']);
```

then do whatever you want

```
echo implode("\n", arrray_map(function($str){
    //query
    return '<div class="coding">'.$str.'</div><div class="green">'.$queryres.'</div><div class="one-more-class"></div>';
}, $ar));
```

Need 5.3 for anonymous functions, you may use not anonimous ones instead.

Manuals:

- [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)
- [explode](http://php.net/explode)
- [implode](http://php.net/implde)

Comment: That works great, but how can I do another implode in this implode?

Comment: @Jack, I'm afraid I don't understand question

Comment: I want to get the array of entries from two `textareas`, and use them in one `implode` function.

Comment: I think you are about `implode($ar1).implode($ar2)`, or about `array_map(function($x, $y){...}, $ar1, $ar2);`